# Input string was not in a correct format in WQL query

Tags: ssis, wmi, ssis-2012, wmi-query, wql

I get the following error :

> [WMI Event Watcher Task] Error: An error occurred with the following
>   error message: "Input string was not in a correct format.".

When I Execute `WQL Query` :

```
SELECT * FROM __InstanceCreationEvent WITHIN 10
WHERE TargetInstance ISA 'CIM_DataFile' AND TargetInstance.Name ='C:\\Users\Mohammed\\Desktop\\Test\\ETL\\ssis-basic-control-flow-tasks\\file_to_watch.txt'
```

---

I try to watch a file like this :

[image]

Comment: I assume your path is `C:\Users\Mohammed\Desktop`. In that case, you need to replace each back slash with 4 back slashes, like this `C:\\\\Users\\\Mohammed\\\\Desktop`. Do the same for the remaining of the path.

Answer (score 0):

```
    //Removes local network printer based
    //on full unc path returns true if successful
    //otherwise false

    public static bool RemoveUnc(string printUncPath)
    {
        ManagementScope oManagementScope = new ManagementScope(ManagementPath.DefaultPath);
        oManagementScope.Connect();

        SelectQuery oSelectQuery = new SelectQuery();
        oSelectQuery.QueryString = @"SELECT * FROM Win32_Printer WHERE Name = '" +
            printUncPath.Replace("\\", "\\\\") + "'";

        ManagementObjectSearcher oObjectSearcher =
            new ManagementObjectSearcher(oManagementScope, oSelectQuery);

        ManagementObjectCollection oObjectCollection = oObjectSearcher.Get();

        if (oObjectCollection.Count != 0)
        {
            foreach (ManagementObject oItem in oObjectCollection)
            {
                oItem.Delete();
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```

I am assuming it is string that includes slashes causing that error. Below is an example I use for removing a printer from a local workstation. Printer share names include a format like "\\printserver\printerShare". Pay attention to the printUncPath.Replace("\\","\\\\"). Think this will solve your problem. Pretty sure you have to escape twice.